# Assert that an enumerable property exists on an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert

Is it possible to use the core Node.js Assert module to check if a property exists on an object even if the property is falsy?

https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

normally we could check if an object has a property by running

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert(obj.prop);
```

but if obj.prop exists but is falsy, this won't work. I prefer using the Node.js assert module and would rather avoid other solutions, thanks.

Perhaps the best way to do this is:

```
    var assert = require('assert');
    assert(prop in obj);
```

Comment: Your second snippet is best, works even if `prop` is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to assert that an enumerable property exists on an object. The suggested code works excellently:

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert(prop in obj);
```

If the property does not exist, an `AssertionError` is thrown.